# Sharepoint 2013 mangement shell gives access denied error when setting $spsite.FileNotFoundUrl attribute

Tags: error, access-denied

I want to set default error page in my site using this command.

```
 $spsite = Get-SPSite "siteurl"
 $spsite.FileNotFoundUrl = "pageurl"
```

But '$spsite.FileNotFoundUrl' gives access denied error. I am site administrator and in my site i have used FBA. This command is working fine for site which is not using FBA.Is this a FBA related issue.

Comment: Is something in the ULS? Set monitoring level to verbose and try it again.